# Return List in xml

Tags: xml, spring, jaxb

Hi I have a class ExerciseInstructions.
I have to return both xml and json response in list.
As jax-b doesnt support top level collection,i am have created another class ExerciseInstructionsList.
I am able to get back the list when i hardcoded the data in controller, But can anyone tell me when m writing the services and Dao classes how can i get that ??
Becoz i have to fetch the data from ExerciseInstructions table which is in db , when i am returning the list by creating new arraylist object in service its showing that cannot convert from ExerciseInstructions to List, Because method signature and class are different, So can any one help??

```
 @RequestMapping(value=EmpRestURIConstants.GET_EXERCISE_ALL,method=RequestMethod.GET,produces={"application/json"})
    public @ResponseBody List<ExerciseInstructions> getAllExercise()throws Exception{

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<--------------Coming Inside List Exercise Controller----------->>>>>>>>>>>");
        List<ExerciseInstructions> listExercise = new ArrayList<ExerciseInstructions>();


        return exerciseService.getAllExercise();
    }




public List<ExerciseInstructions> getAllExercise() throws Exception{



    return excerciseDao.getAllExercise();
}
```

Here I have mentioned the service and controller layers.
my moto is to return both json and xml list.
I can easily return json but for xml I have to write a separate list class.
so how can I get both responses as list??
because when ever I have return the list its showing unable to convet ExerciseInstructions class to ExerciseInstructionsList class.
Can any one help?

Comment: do you have code to share?

Comment: Yes I can tomorrow I will do that...